# Knockout visible binding not getting reevaluated

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm a bit puzzled with knockout visible binding.
I created a sample to demonstrate the problem.
The main goal is to show some div (otherDetails) when the user selects "other" option.
It's not working.
The visible is not getting revaluated when the "mySelection" field is getting changed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <title>Test</title> 

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    function data() 
    { 
            this.mySelection =  ko.observable('other'); 

            this.isOtherSelected = ko.computed(function () 
            { 
                    return this.mySelection.peek() == 'other'; 
            }, this); 
    } 

    var myData = new data(); 

    $(document).ready(function () 
    { 
             $('#selections').change(function () 
             { 
                 myData.mySelection = $(this).val();         
             }); 

            dataBind(); 
    }); 

    function dataBind() 
    { 
            ko.applyBindings(myData); 
    } 
    </script> 
</head> 

<body> 
        <div> 
                <select id="selections" data-bind="value: mySelection"> 
                    <option value='one'>One</option> 
                    <option value='two'>Two</option> 
                    <option value='three'>Three</option> 
                    <option value='other'>Other</option> 
                </select> 
        </div> 
        <div id="otherDetails" data-bind="visible: isOtherSelected"> 
            <span>Some controls and stuff...</span> 
        </div> 
</body>
```

Thanks in advance, Yaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `peek()`:
`return this.mySelection() == 'other';`

peek function gets value of observable, but do not subscribe outer computed observable on changes. Because of that, your binding is not reevaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with observables in different way. Every observable is a function so to get value you have to call it:

```
return this.mySelection() == 'other';
```

If you want to assign value to it you should pass value to this function:

```
myData.mySelection($(this).val());
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkGRs/

P.S. You don't need to use jQuery change handler there. KO will automatically update value of the observable. Here is refactored code: http://jsfiddle.net/kkGRs/1/